# javascripts objects programing tips

Tags: javascript, oop

i'm new to object oriented javascript so while i was practicing i created this code here :

```js
ap = []; //creating an empty array to hold persons;


    pp = function (f, l, a, n, g) { //this is our object constructor
        this.fname = f;
        this.lname = l;
        this.dob = a;
        this.nat = n;
        this.gen = g;
    };


     ap[ap.length] = new pp(f, l, a, n, g); // adding the newely created person to our array through the constructor function . btw parameters passed to the function are defined in another  function ( details in the jsfiddle file)
```

[Here's the full code sample](https://jsfiddle.net/g16u1a69/)

the purpose from this code is to get used to objects creation and manipulation . so i waswondering if there is any easier way and more logical method to fulfill the same task .

well anyhelp would be appreciated and thanks.

Comment: @ray that's a terrible advice.

Comment: ty @ray i really appreciate your advice ty again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just have a look at the **factory design pattern** and all the other design patterns at http://www.addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#factorypatternjavascript. They are good practice and will definitely push you in the right direction. The **factory pattern** could be some overhead if you're just building a small application, but creating objects from a single method `factory.create()` gives you the ability to change things quickly in the future.
Some people also prefer to pass an object with attributes to the factory.

I would create a tiny factory which manages the store as well:

```
var ppFactory = {
    _store: [],
    _objectClass: PP,

    create: function (args) {
        var pp = new this._objectClass(args);
        this._store.push(pp);
        return pp;
    },

    remove: function (id) {
    },

    get: function (id) {
    }

};

var pp = ppFactory.create({
    f: f,
    l: l,
    a: a,
    n: n,
    g: g
});
```

hope that helps!

Comment: ty for your help @Jörn i will consider your example .

Comment: @Fayçal you're welcome! don't forget to mark this thread as answered if i answered your question :)

Comment: well @Jörn ty again i found really good javascript design patterns but i asked this question to get advices and techniques and discuss them with people who know them better than me